# Java service auto kill on linux

Tags: java, jar, nohup

I have ran *nohup java -jar sample.jar &* on my linux server as a backend service of web application but service is automatically killed after few hours and need to re-run the command.
I want to know what is the reason and how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run Spring Boot via the same command and only a handful of times have I seen this behavior.  It turned out that the JVM ran out of memory and it crashed.  When I changed the heap size settings it was rock solid again.

Comment: If this is the problem, you should see an `OutOfMemoryError` exception in the application logs, or standard output or error ... or somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, one possibility is that it is the `oomkiller` process.  This watches for processes that appears to be triggering excessive paging activity, and sends them a `SIGKILL` signal.  The oom killer's purpose is to prevent the paging system from *thrashing* ... which can bring the entire system to its knees.

If it is the oom killer killing your Java app, you should see a log message in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.

The solution may be as simple as reducing the Java app's heap size so that it all fits in the available *physical* memory.  Alternatively, if your Java app's heap usage is growing all of the time, you may need to look for a possible memory leak in your app.  (Search for articles on finding Java memory leaks ...)